# Unable to click link to get rid of tour popup

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to click on the **'End Tour'** link in order to close a perky popup, as in the attached screenshot. My goal is to get rid of the popup entirely, as it is stopping me from moving past that screen during my tests.

I have tried to using `cssSelector`, `xpath` and `linkText`, none of which seem to be working.  See the HTML bellow and the browser console of the inspected popup element shown below:

[image]

```
<div class="popover-navigation">
    <a data-role="prev" class="disabled" tabindex="-1">« Prev</a>
    <span data-role="separator">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <a data-role="next">Next »</a>
    <a data-role="end">End Tour</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please place code in your question not as in image.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I see your problem, you might be using the correct selectors, but the element your are trying to find apparently resides in an `iframe`(see closing `</iframe>` tag in your console). So basically your popup is opened in a different window, and displayed in your current TAB via an [**iframe**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

You will need to `.switchTo()` your driver context, to the one of your iframe (which I will consider as having `id="carlsonIframe"`, due to lack of `<iframe>` tag attributes). Should look something like this:

```
// We have to switch to the popup:
driver.switchTo().frame("carlsonIframe");

// And now click the 'End Tour' button:
driver.findElement(By.css("div.popover-navigation a:contains('End Tour')")).click();
// or: driver.findElement(By.css("div.popover-navigation a:nth-of-type(3)")).click();

// Finally, go back to your original context:
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Let me know if this works for you. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I tried the above suggestion and got the following error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id carlsonIframe

Comment: @ChitChinwah can you please check/confirm that your popup is situated in an iframe (between <iframe> tags, and if so, update your snippet of code? We can then see what ID, Name, Attributes your iframe has in order to identify it & switch the context to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not best way but you can use that code for skip the walk me popup.

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='popover-navigation']/a[@data-role='end']")).click();
}catch (NoSuchElementException ignore) {
    logger.info("walk me popup didn't seen")
}
```

Comment: Hi, tried your suggestion and got the following error message: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='popover-navigation']/a[@data-role='end']"}

Comment: Did you see that ever it close walk me popup ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is an `<iframe>` in the Document Object Model (DOM) / HTML Source, you have to switch to it first, using `driver.switchTo().frame("NAME_OR_ID_OF_THE_IFRAME");`

In your case,

```
// Switch to the iframe
driver.switchTo().frame("kdsiframe");

// Locate the element by link Text
driver.findElement(By.linkText("End Tour")).click();

// Switch back to default content
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

After switching to the iframe, these are the following ways you can locate the 'End Tour' link:

1. Link Text:

```
By lnkEndTour = By.linkText("End Tour");
```

2. XPATH:

```
By xpEndTour = By.xpath("//*[@id='index-page']//*[contains(@id,'step')]//a[@data-role='end' and contains(text(),'End Tour')]");
```

Comment: I'm just curious as to what is the added value your answer brought vs. others previous answers. The new locator-strategies proposed bring nothing new to the table. Moreover `linkText` is not a best practice due to countless **Localization** changes that might occur. Also your `xpath` selector is not optimized.

Comment: 1. I'm using the correct iframe name/id. 2. The answers specifically caters to the question which does not mention that there will be localization involved. 3. Xpath has been used to get the element for sure, it doesn't have to be optimized as the priority here is not performance but working code.

Answer (score 0):

May be your trying to access the frame elements before it is loading. So wait for the frame to load and find the element and do the action.

You can use explicit wait as given below.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("frameID"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".popover-navigation>a[data-role='end']")).click();
```

Change the frameID here.